# calling method channel in fcm onbackgroundmessage flutter for setshowonlockscreen

Tags: flutter, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-local-notification

im trying to make an alert screen in the phones lockscreen.
im currently using flutter_local_notifications to try and run the screen on fullscreen intent and route to another screen.
the problem im having is in the firebasemessaging onbackgroundmessage, as i try to run the methodchannel in the onbackgroundmessage it gives me this error
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method turnScreenOnAndKeyguardOff on channel com.example.myapp/actions)
ive been trying lots of ways also for the routing tried with flutter local notifications use didnotificaitonlaunchapp and i want didnotificaitonopenapp.

so the questions are:
1.how can i run in the onbackgroundmessage a methodchannel and invoke a function in mainactivity.kt
2.how can i route from if message recieved.

thanks in advance!

this is my code:

main.dart:

```
 FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin notificationsPlugin =
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await FirebaseAuthImpl().signInAnonymously();
  FirebaseAlert().initNotifications();
  runApp(
    
       const App(),
    );
  
}
```

firebase_alert.dart:

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:alarmplayer/alarmplayer.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:myapp/services/notification_service.dart';


Future<void> handleBackgroundMessage(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  print('Title : ${message.notification?.title}');
  print('Body : ${message.notification?.body}');
  print('Payload : ${message.data}');


 Future<void> playAudio(String soundName) async {
    Alarmplayer alarmplayer = Alarmplayer();
    bool playing = false;

    void switchPlaying() {
      playing = !playing;
    }

    try {
      await alarmplayer.Alarm(
        url: "assets/sounds/$soundName.wav",
        volume: 1,
        looping: false,
        callback: switchPlaying,
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error playing sound: $e');
    }
  }

  if (message.data.containsKey('alert_type_name')) {
    final String alertTypeName = message.data['alert_type_name'];
    print('Alert Type: $alertTypeName');
  }

  if (message.data.containsKey("alert_type_name")) {
    final String alertTypeName = message.data["alert_type_name"];
    // await playAudio(alertTypeName);
  }
  await futureShowNotification();

}

class FirebaseAlert {
  

  Future<void> initNotifications() async {

    FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging =  FirebaseMessaging.instance;
    await firebaseMessaging.requestPermission(
      alert: true,
      announcement: false,
      badge: true,
      carPlay: true,
      criticalAlert: true,
      provisional: false,
      sound: true,
    );

    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(handleBackgroundMessage);
    final fCMToken = await firebaseMessaging.getToken();
    print('token: $fCMToken');  
  }
}
```

notification_service.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:myapp/main.dart';

Future<void> initNotifications() async {
  AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
    const AndroidInitializationSettings("darohicon");

    var initializationSettingsIOS = const DarwinInitializationSettings(
      requestAlertPermission: true,
      requestBadgePermission: true,
      requestCriticalPermission: true,
      requestProvisionalPermission: true,
      requestSoundPermission: true
    );

    var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
      android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
      iOS: initializationSettingsIOS
    );
  await notificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse:(NotificationResponse notificationResponse) async {  
  });
}

notificationDetails(){
  return const NotificationDetails(
    android: AndroidNotificationDetails("high_importance_channel", "High Importance Notifications",icon:"@mipmap/darohicon",importance: Importance.max,fullScreenIntent: true),
    iOS: DarwinNotificationDetails()
    
  );
}

Future<void> futureShowNotification({
  int id = 0, String? title, String? body, String? payload
}) async {
  MethodChannel platform = await const MethodChannel('com.example.myapp/actions');

  await _turnScreenOnAndKeyguardOff(platform);
  
  // The screen-related action is complete at this point
  // Perform other tasks
  notificationsPlugin.cancelAll();
  return notificationsPlugin.show(id, title, body, await notificationDetails());
}

Future<void> _turnScreenOnAndKeyguardOff(MethodChannel platform) async {
  try {
    await platform.invokeMethod('turnScreenOnAndKeyguardOff');
  } on PlatformException catch (e) {
    print("Error: ${e.message}");
  }
}

Future<void> _restoreDefaultFlags(MethodChannel platform) async {
  try {
    await platform.invokeMethod('restoreDefaultFlags');
  } on PlatformException catch (e) {
    print("Error: ${e.message}");
  }
}
```

mainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.myapp

import android.content.Context
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.WindowManager
import android.app.KeyguardManager
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin

class MainActivity : io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity() {
    private val CHANNEL = "com.example.myapp/actions"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        flutterEngine?.plugins?.add(FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin())
    }
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)

        MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL)
            .setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
                when (call.method) {
                    "turnScreenOnAndKeyguardOff" -> {
                        turnScreenOnAndKeyguardOff()
                        result.success(null)
                    }
                    "restoreDefaultFlags" -> {
                        restoreDefaultFlags()
                        result.success(null)
                    }
                    else -> result.notImplemented()
                }
            }
    }

    private fun turnScreenOnAndKeyguardOff() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
            setShowWhenLocked(true)
            setTurnScreenOn(true)
        } else {
            window.addFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                        or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALLOW_LOCK_WHILE_SCREEN_ON
            )
        }

        with(getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE) as KeyguardManager) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                requestDismissKeyguard(this@MainActivity, null)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun restoreDefaultFlags() {
        // Remove the flags that were set in turnScreenOnAndKeyguardOff
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
            setShowWhenLocked(false)
            setTurnScreenOn(false)
        } else {
            window.clearFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                        or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALLOW_LOCK_WHILE_SCREEN_ON
            )
        }
    }
}
```

for the fullscreenintent notification i tried onbackgroundmessage with methodchannel, tried to get context in the function but it did not work.
i think all did not work because its a static function unless im wrong.

for the routing i tried
from the firebasemessaging plugin : onintialmessage, onmessage, onbackgroundmessage,
from flutter_local_notifications : ondidlaunchapp